# what does "in-memory" means ? In the context of hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I read this line

> when you are starting namenode, latest fsimage file is load into “in-memory”. and at the same time, edit log file is also loaded into memory if fsimage file doesn’t contain up-to date information

from https://data-flair.training/forums/topic/in-which-location-namenode-stores-its-metadata-and-why/
they are using term "in-memory" and "memory" are they different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they aren't different.  They are loaded into [RandomAccessFile](https://github.com/naver/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NNStorage.java) if that helps to think about.  For reference here is [FSImage](https://github.com/naver/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/FSImage.java). To help you see how this is done.